# Code works as a regular function, but not as a Cypress command

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I created a function that is supposed to click a dropdown to open it and then check if the options I passed are there. It goes like this:

```js
function dropdown(placeholderText: string) {
  function contains(...values: string[]) {
    cy.contains(placeholderText).click();
    values.map((value) => cy.contains(value));
  }

  return { contains };
}

it('should show a dropdown with the correct options', () => {
  dropdown('Proteins').contains('Steak', 'Chicken Breast, 'Eggs', 'Fish')
})
```

So far, so good. It works fine. Then I tried to turn it into a Cypress command to make reuse easier:

```js
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    dropdown: (placeholderText: string) => any;
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('dropdown', (placeholderText: string) => {
  function contains(...values: string[]) {
    cy.contains(placeholderText).click();
    values.map((value) => cy.contains(value));
  }

  return { contains };
});
```

It gives me a type error in the command implementation. although it's kinda cryptic...

```
Argument of type '(placeholderText: string) => { contains: (...values: string[]) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => CanReturnChainable'.
  Type '{ contains: (...values: string[]) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'CanReturnChainable'.
    Type '{ contains: (...values: string[]) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Chainable<any>': dropdown, and, as, blur, and 81 more.
```

It seems like it was expecting me to return some Cypress chainable value but I returned something else. Don't know how to fix it. It still ran, though! But when it was time to run my custom command, I got this error:

```
cy.contains() failed because it requires the subject be a global window object.

The subject received was:

  > {contains: function(){}}

The previous command that ran was:

  > cy.dropdown()

All 3 subject validations failed on this subject.
```

What am I supposed to do here? It seems like one error (the typescript one) has something to do with the other (the cypress one), but I don't know how to fix them.

#### Image

[image: a screenshot of the Cypress log. It shows this line of code highlighted, depicting where the error occurred: cy.dropdown('Escolha um tipo de bem').contains(]

Answer (score 0):

The Function version is a higher-order function, returning a function that can be called with additional parameters.

The common example (not as fluent as your version) is

```js
function dropdown2(placeholderText: string) {
  return function(...values: string[]) {
    cy.contains(placeholderText).click();
    values.map((value) => cy.contains(value));
  }
}

dropdown2('Proteins')('Steak','Eggs')
//or
const contains = dropdown2('Proteins')
contains('Steak','Eggs')
```

---

Cypress chaining is different, it always returns a `Chainable<T>`.

To use your `dropdown` command as it is at the moment, you need to unwrap the `Chainable`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('dropdown', (placeholderText: string) => {
  function contains(...values: string[]) {
    cy.contains(placeholderText).click();
    values.map((value) => cy.contains(value));
  }
  return { contains };
});

cy.dropdown('Proteins').then(({contains}) => contains('Steak','Eggs'))  // ✅
```

To make it a little easier to unwrap, return the `contains` function without an object wrapper.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('dropdown', (placeholderText: string) => {
  function contains(...values: string[]) {
    cy.contains(placeholderText).click();
    values.map((value) => cy.contains(value));
  }
  return contains
});

cy.dropdown('Proteins').then(contains => contains('Steak','Eggs'))  // ✅
```

To keep the fluent syntax, convert both outer and inner functions to custom commands.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('dropdown', (placeholderText: string) => {
  cy.contains(placeholderText).click();
});

Cypress.Commands.add('hasItems', {prevSubject: true}, (subject, ...values) => {
  cy.wrap(subject).within(() => {
    values.forEach((value) => cy.contains(value));
  })
});

cy.dropdown('Proteins').hasItems('Steak','Eggs')
```

Also add `.within()`, otherwise there is no connection between the dropdown and the inner items. Without it `Steak` and `Eggs` could appear anywhere on the page and the test would succeed.

Same applies to previous versions.